# How do I get awesome_print to work without using ~/.irbrc file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, awesomeprint

I want to use awesome print without putting it in my rails 5 app. Just in the console. The documentation for requiring it in irb is not working.

Answer (score 1):

That's because bundler isolates the gems available to load to what's in your `Gemfile`.

The best way to get around this is to add the gem to your `Gemfile`

```
gem 'awesome_print', require: false, group: :development
```

And in your `.irbrc`, you can `require` it, so that it is only enabled for you:

```
begin
  require 'awesome_print'
rescue LoadError => err
  warn "could not require awesome_print: #{err}"
end
```

However, if you aren't permitted to add awesome_print to your repository for whatever reason, there are a few hacks to get gems installed, but not in your `Gemfile` to load in [this GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/skojin/794915/c4fe11bf964da437b7cd0b82928a9c6c89473763).

One such example that could be placed at the top of your `.irbrc`:

```
# Add all gems in the global gemset to the $LOAD_PATH so they can be used even
# in places like 'rails console'.
if defined?(::Bundler)
  global_gemset = ENV['GEM_PATH'].split(':').grep(/ruby.*@global/).first
  $LOAD_PATH.concat(Dir.glob("#{global_gemset}/gems/*/lib")) if 
  global_gemset
end
```

Comment: Thank you Unixmonkey,
Forgive my ignorance but I do not know where to find the .irbrc file in the rails 5 app. I am a learning newbie.
Is there a way to use it without putting it in the Gemfile?

Comment: The .irbc file should go in your users root directory.  Then when you have a Rails app with Awesomeprint in the gemfile, it will be used in Rails console.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd your/rails/project
irb
```

inside irb, run:

```
require 'awesome_print'
require './config/environment'
```

and you have both rails console and awesome_print gem while the gem is installed outside of the bundler.